# Mount Windows File Share and acces them on ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: networking, server, mount, samba

I have created a windows file share windows server 2012 on one of the data centre and I want to access the file share in another data centre on Ubuntu server 14.04

I am able to ping both the machines vice versa.
I have installed `cifs-utils` on the Ubuntu machine and when I run the

```
$ mount.cifs //x.x.x.x/test /mnt/iweb -o user=Administrator
Password:
```

Windows Share is not getting mounted on the machine.
Correct me if am wrong on the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
mount –t cifs //servername/sharename /mountpoint –o username=userid
```

It will ask for the password, once you enter this command.

Also make sure that you have cifs share entry in /etc/fstab

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried the same mount –t cifs //servername/sharename /mountpoint –o username=userid i gave the password and after some time i get an error message time out.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo mount -t smbfs -o username=domainname\\username,password=userpassword  //servername/sharename /mountpointname
```